# MYSQL Insert...on duplicate value insert again with increment

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have 5 columns a, b, c, d and e.
I want to insert values into first 4 columns and have kept default value as 1 in last column.
I have kept the first 4 columns as primary keys.
If duplicate values are inserted in the first 4 columns, then I want to insert the same values again but with increment in the 5th column.
Eg: if 1,2,3,4 are values for the first 4 columns. then when 1,2,3,4 comes again they need to be inserted as 1,2,3,4 but with fifth column as 2.

Comment: all i am finding is on duplicate update...but i dont want to update. i want to insert again

Comment: is there a function for on duplicate insert. and i tried if exists but it doesnt seem to work for mysql

Comment: Primary key has a unique constraint so your database would reject such a insert

Comment: if primary keys are not used, and there are 5 columns say a,b,c,d,e with e having default value 1. then when duplicate values are encountered for a,b,c,d then i want to store them in the database with e incremented by 1. how do i check whether a,b,c,d are duplicates?

Comment: `insert into tbl_abc set a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1,e=1 on duplicate key update insert into tbl_abc set a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1,e=1+1;` All the 5 column should have unique key constraint commutatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the primary key and add a unique key instead.

```
ALTER TABLE test DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD UNIQUE KEY 'test_uIdx_a_b_c_d_e' ( a,b,c,d,e );
```

Assuming your table now looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    a int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    b int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    c int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    d int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    e int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    UNIQUE KEY 'test_uIdx_a_b_c_d_e' ( a,b,c,d,e )
)
```

Then you can create a trigger on before insert

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER before_test_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.e := ( SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM test WHERE a = NEW.a AND b = NEW.b AND c = NEW.c AND d = NEW.d;
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

This will set field e to the number of occurrences of a,b,c,d

One of the comments above offered a simpler alternative

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 1):

If first four columns are primary key , then you cannot 1,2,3,4 once again

i.e

Taking 
Col 1,Col 2, Col 3, Col 4

1,2,3,4 - Ok 
2,1,3,4 - Ok
2,3,1,4 - Ok
1,4,3,2 - Ok
.. Like 4 C 4 combination

but

1,2,3,4 - Ok
1,2,3,4 - Again, it would be an error!

So you cannot insert 1,2,3,4 once again!

Comment: let us forget about the primary keys. if the same 4 values come again then I want to store them in the database again and increment the value in the 5th column

Comment: You add a new column say serial_no, and mark that as primary key instead of these 4 columns. And now u insert normally. It should work!